# SwiftUI Unable to resize Image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create image in SwiftUI and the problem I am facing is that image is not resizing itself even if I set content mode fill

```
struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("app-icon")
                .frame(width: percent(80, ofSize: "width"), height: percent(40, ofSize: "width"), alignment: Alignment.center)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fill)
                .scaledToFill()
                .clipped()

    }
}
```

Then I tried

```
struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("app-icon")
                .frame(width: percent(80, ofSize: "width"), height: percent(40, ofSize: "width"), alignment: Alignment.center)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()

    }
}
```

[image]

Both Code has same effect image size is not changed

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `.resizable()` as the first modifier after Image for the other modifiers to have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

- Add `.resizable()` modifier to your code

  ```
  Image("app-icon")
     .resizable()
     .scaledToFill()
     .frame(width: percent(80, ofSize: "width"), height: percent(40, ofSize: "width"), alignment: Alignment.center)
     .clipped()
  ```