# How to set width and height of an image in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to set height and width of an image . I've tried using following code but it didn't work.

```
 Image("testImg")
  .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Unable to resize Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743580/swiftui-unable-to-resize-image)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743580/swiftui-unable-to-resize-image/58745013#58745013

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Image("testImg")
.resizable()
.frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 Image("testImg")
     .resizable()
     .scaledToFit()
     .frame(width: 50,height:50)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var body: some View {

            Image("yourImage")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 50.0, height:50.0)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Image(restaurant.image)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .clipShape(Circle())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Image("testImg")
 .resizable()
 .scaledToFit()
 .frame(width: required-width,height:required-height)
```