# How i can set width and height of an image using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to set height and width of an image . I've tried using following code but it doen't affect the width and height of my image.

```html
Image("myImg")
  .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
```

please help..

Comment: Follow this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264975/2641798